# Python 3: search text file with user input?

Tags: python, file, search, text, input

there is a part of my program where I would like to pass a sorted list of names from a text file to a function which asks the user to enter a name and then indicate whether the name entered is found in the list or not.  If the name is found, its position (i.e. index) is also printed.

The file is just 30 names, but when the second function is executed, it will show this after I input which name I would like to search for:
name not found.
name not found.
name found
name not found.
name not found.
...etc for all 30 names.

Here's the code:

```
def main():
    infile = open('names.txt', 'r')
    line = infile.readline()

    while line !='':
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        print(line)
        line = infile.readline()

    print('\nHere are the names sorted:\n')

    infile = open("names.txt", 'r')
    names = infile.readlines()
    names.sort()

    for line in names:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        print(line)
        line = infile.readline()
        search_file(line) # I don't this this is the correct way to
                          # pass the sorted list of names?


def search_file(line):
    search = open('names.txt', 'r')
    user_search = input('\nSearch for a name(Last, First): ')
    #item_index = line.index(search)
    print()

    with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if user_search in line:
                print('name found')#, item_index)
            else:
                print('name not found.')
```

updated code here:
this time it always displays "not found"

```
def search_file(line):

user_search = input('\nSearch for a name(Last, First): ')
print()

try:
    item_index = line.index(user_search)
    print(user_search, 'found at index', item_index)

except ValueError:
    print('not found.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first you would only want to open the file you are searching one time.  You could load all lines in the file into a list with .readlines() this function returns a string in a list for each line.  Then you can search for the user string with in each line with

```
for l in lines:
   if (l.find(userstring)>-1):
       foundvar=True
```

Comment: I tried using "try/except ValueError", but now it will only print the ValueError or "not found" print statement

Comment: @twenty-three Would need to see the new and updated code.

Comment: I added the updated piece to the original post.  Forgive me, I'm very new to coding.